# Why do my stats not always increase in Call of Duty Black-Ops? 

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I've been in the process of shooting down spy planes for the Ghost perk.  I was checking the challenges menu after each match, but the number of aircraft shot down doesn't always increase. For some it did, but for others it didn't. Has anyone experienced that?  Maybe it is a delayed process and will add to the count later?

I had it happen again with playing demolition; I needed 2 plants to get to Ninja Pro, I got 5, and it gave me credit for only one.

What's causing this to happen, and is there something I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a number of things that *could* prevent you from banking the kills you earned!  I have never seen any sort of delayed gratification in any of the Call of Duty games where the challenges were not immediately updated. Here is the list that I can come up with:

Ghost pro requires: Destroy 30 aircraft with any non-Killstreak launcher.
                 Is it possible you're using the wrong weapon?

Someone else shoots it:  It happens unfortunately.  You feel like the hero of your team but a heat seeking rocket is already blazing through the sky to steal your fame.

Its just dumb:  Honestly, I would probably chalk it up to this.  I haven't explicitly heard of a bug that occurs when shooting down spyplanes, but that doesn't mean the counter is 100% accurate 100% of the time.

I hope this helps!

Edit:  I have found good evidence to support it is actually an in-game bug and seems consistent across all of the consoles.  Here is a link to one such [thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960189-/57679613) discussing the problem.

Comment: It popped up the message: brought down a spyplane!  Oh well, maybe it was a freak thing, or maybe even me...

Comment: @Brian I did a little more searching and found that players have reported the counter getting 'stuck' on xbox.  It will register up to a certain point, say 25 then fail to register anymore.  Eventually it will 'unstick' and allow you to progress in your achievement.  This reaffirms my suspicions that it was probably a game bug.  I'll update my answer with a link!

Comment: Yes it just happened to me, I needed two plants to get Ninja pro, I got 4, and it gave me credit for only 1... definitely a bug.  Thanks.